# How do I use bot.anything with cogs?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

**I trying to make a discord bot and Um implementing music function and for this I need to use codes like** `bot.voice_clients` **and the command dont really work if I put them in any cog file however works perfectly if I put in main.py**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

class music(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

@bot.command()
async def join(self, ctx):
    global voice
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(self.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()
        print(f"The bot has connected to {channel}\n")

    await ctx.message.add_reaction('\U0001F44C')

@bot.command()
async def leave(self, ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(self.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await ctx.message.add_reaction('\U0001F44B')
        await voice.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Im not connected")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(music(bot))
```

**this is what i get in terminal if a try to do that**

```
PS D:\Documentos\Predo\yunna-bot\yunna-bot-master> & C:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe d:/Documentos/Predo/yunna-bot/yunna-bot-master/main_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 596, in _load_from_module_spec
    spec.loader.exec_module(lib)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "d:\Documentos\Predo\yunna-bot\yunna-bot-master\cogs\music.py", line 10, in <module>
    @bot.command()
NameError: name 'bot' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Documentos/Predo/yunna-bot/yunna-bot-master/main_test.py", line 33, in <module>
    bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
  File "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 653, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 599, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.music' raised an error: NameError: name 'bot' is not defined
PS D:\Documentos\Predo\yunna-bot\yunna-bot-master>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [cogs page of the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html) for some examples. For this, you need to use `commands.command` as the decorator instead of `bot.command` (because when the cog class is defined, you don't have the bot instance)

```
class music(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):
        ...
```

Comment: I've read the documentation and tried to use command instead of bot but inside the code I didn't know what to put in "bot.etc" would it be command? tks you a lot for answer me btw

Comment: When you're using cogs try preceding any mentions of bot with `self.` (e.g `self.bot.latency`)